# How to add a virtual host on a folder that is located on another computer?

Tags: apache, vhosts, zend-server-ce

I have Zend Server installed on my machine (windows 7 home edition) and I´m trying to set up a virtual host on a folder that is located in our server. For some reasons, I can't set an apache web server in there, so it must be done in my own computer.

But I can't get it done. My virtual host setup in httpd-vhosts.conf is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerAdmin web@web.com.br
    DocumentRoot "\Data\Websites\Online\TheClientName\Site"
    ServerName clientname.local
    ServerAlias clientname.local
    ErrorLog "logs/clientname.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

And the hosts file:

```
172.17.10.1/Data/Websites/Online/TheClientName/Site        clientname.local
```

I have checked the Apache log. There's a Warning:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Data/Websites/Online/TheClientName/Site] does not exist
```

I got full access to this folder, and I have it mapped like a local drive. I tried to set the DocumentRoot as follows, but no luck; Apache does not restarts after setting the 'Z:\'.

```
"Z:\Data\Websites\Online\TheClientName\Site"
```

I wonder if there is a way to point this v-host to server folder. Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to use Z: if it is mounted and you can browse it - what output from `httpd -t` do you get if you using `Z:\`?

Comment: @LeonardChallis 
Thanks for your attention. Yeah, it is mounted. Apache gives me an syntax error pointing to the line where I have declared the Z folder and a "DocumentRoot must be a directory" message. Running the httpd -t I just got a "Syntax OK" message from the command line.